# How WatchKit handles images?

Tags: ios, memory, optimization, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

I've just a question: **what is the real difference** between saving the images on the WatchKit App or saving them on the iOS App/WatchKit Extension?

I mean, the images saved on the WatchKit App are really saved on the Watch? If I save a lot of images on the WatchKit App, **is there any limit about an app size**?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is the real difference?**

The real difference is that images saved into the `Watch App` are going to be installed on the Watch. Images saved into the `Watch Extension` are going to be saved on the iOS device.

> This is a **VERY** important distinction because it is very slow to add a cached image using the `WKInterfaceDevice` APIs. Any static images for your Watch App MUST be stored in your Watch App and not your Watch Extension. Only dynamic images that are generated by the iOS App or Watch Extension should need to use the `WKInterfaceDevice` caching APIs.

**Is there any limit to app size?**

Apple has not publicly posted any limits. One could speculate that there most likely is a limit.

Comment: The documentation does state that there is 5MB available for the watch image cache. These are images generated in the phone extension and copied to the device. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Images.html